# React Native - Open mail client with body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, react-native

I'm using npm pacakge to open mail client with data:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mail-compose

Also, I'm using their example:

```
import MailCompose from 'react-native-mail-compose';

// later in your code...
async sendMail() {
  try {
    await MailCompose.send({
      toRecipients: ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
      ccRecipients: ['cc1@example.com'],
      bccRecipients: ['bcc1@example.com', 'bcc2@example.com'],
      subject: 'This is subject',
      text: 'This is body',
      html: '<p>This is <b>html</b> body</p>', // Or, use this if you want html body. Note that some Android mail clients / devices don't support this properly.
      attachments: [{
        filename: 'mytext', // [Optional] If not provided, UUID will be generated.
        ext: '.txt',
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        text: 'Hello my friend', // Use this if the data is in UTF8 text.
        data: '...BASE64_ENCODED_STRING...', // Or, use this if the data is not in plain text.
      }],
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // e.code may be 'cannotSendMail' || 'cancelled' || 'saved' || 'failed'
  }
}
```

and call this function on button press. All data is OK, except body, for example here in Subject there is "This is subject", in CC of mail clients, there is "cc1@example.com", but **body is always empty**, I can't ever see "This is body" in mail client.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it with another package [react-native-send-intent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-intent).
It works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see, give this package a try. 
https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications
Its very simple to use

Comment: Thanks for answer, I just did it 5 minutes ago with this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-intent
It's working great! :)

Comment: Sounds great :)